# nifi 3 node docker + ssl getting Untrusted proxy CN=localhost, OU=NIFI

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-nifi

Followed detailed instructions to set up a 3 node docker hosted nifi cluster + ssl with standalone certificate. Steps that are taken:

1. set up docker to start up persistent 3 node nifi cluster (nifi01,nifi02,nifi03,registry and nifi_zookeeper)
2. since they all are in docker bridged network, hostnames are set as above. However in order to access UI, I used ssh tunnel to proxy as "localhost:8443:remotehost:6950" . so I can access them from browser as "https://localhost:8443/nifi".
3. Then set up oidc for which need ssl . so generated cert and kept it in shared location.

```
./bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n localhost --subjectAlternativeNames 'localhost,0.0.0.0,nifi01,nifi02,nifi03,nifi_registry'
```

4. followed : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#cluster-node-identities and set up authorizers.xml which created users.xml /authorizations.xml as below

authorizers.xml

```
<userGroupProvider>
    <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
    <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
    <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

    <property name="Initial User Identity 1">xyz@oidc.domain.com</property>
    <property name="Initial User Identity 2">CN=nifi01, OU=NIFI</property>
    <property name="Initial User Identity 3">CN=nifi02, OU=NIFI</property>
    <property name="Initial User Identity 4">CN=nifi03, OU=NIFI</property>
</userGroupProvider>
<accessPolicyProvider>
    <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
    <property name="User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
    <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
    <property name="Initial Admin Identity">xyz@oidc.domain.com</property>
    <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
    <property name="Node Identity 1">CN=nifi01, OU=NIFI</property>
    <property name="Node Identity 2">CN=nifi02, OU=NIFI</property>
    <property name="Node Identity 3">CN=nifi03, OU=NIFI</property>
    <property name="Node Group"></property>
</accessPolicyProvider>
<authorizer>
    <identifier>managed-authorizer</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.StandardManagedAuthorizer</class>
    <property name="Access Policy Provider">file-access-policy-provider</property>
</authorizer>
```

which generated users.xml and authorizations.xml as :
users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tenants>
    <groups/>
    <users>
        <user identifier="c3f09c4d-0c92-3f45-b2e4-877def626d99" identity="CN=nifi02, OU=NIFI"/>
        <user identifier="882592de-bfd2-35fa-b447-e6866f066684" identity="CN=nifi01, OU=NIFI"/>
        <user identifier="bae641ef-8e45-3838-8dde-8e012ada53f5" identity="CN=nifi03, OU=NIFI"/>
        <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814" identity="xyz@oidc.domain.com"/>
    </users>
</tenants>
```

authorizations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<authorizations>
    <policies>
        <policy identifier="f99bccd1-a30e-3e4a-98a2-dbc708edc67f" resource="/flow" action="R">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="4962996d-5f2e-3c80-94b3-1eaa2d71cedc" resource="/data/process-groups/2fa42d02-b336-30cd-aa96-f1aea310af6f" action="R">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
            <user identifier="c3f09c4d-0c92-3f45-b2e4-877def626d99"/>
            <user identifier="882592de-bfd2-35fa-b447-e6866f066684"/>
            <user identifier="bae641ef-8e45-3838-8dde-8e012ada53f5"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="cf5bec73-a284-3fae-811c-3e40e3db25e6" resource="/data/process-groups/2fa42d02-b336-30cd-aa96-f1aea310af6f" action="W">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
            <user identifier="c3f09c4d-0c92-3f45-b2e4-877def626d99"/>
            <user identifier="882592de-bfd2-35fa-b447-e6866f066684"/>
            <user identifier="bae641ef-8e45-3838-8dde-8e012ada53f5"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="1e6048dc-8ba2-34ee-a641-a1e260c55d75" resource="/process-groups/2fa42d02-b336-30cd-aa96-f1aea310af6f" action="R">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="92d7b372-f63a-30ab-a107-f70ea0bbc8d9" resource="/process-groups/2fa42d02-b336-30cd-aa96-f1aea310af6f" action="W">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="b8775bd4-704a-34c6-987b-84f2daf7a515" resource="/restricted-components" action="W">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="627410be-1717-35b4-a06f-e9362b89e0b7" resource="/tenants" action="R">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="15e4e0bd-cb28-34fd-8587-f8d15162cba5" resource="/tenants" action="W">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="ff96062a-fa99-36dc-9942-0f6442ae7212" resource="/policies" action="R">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="ad99ea98-3af6-3561-ae27-5bf09e1d969d" resource="/policies" action="W">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="2e1015cb-0fed-3005-8e0d-722311f21a03" resource="/controller" action="R">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="c6322e6c-4cc1-3bcc-91b3-2ed2111674cf" resource="/controller" action="W">
            <user identifier="52b536d4-50ee-351a-9f9a-1f9ee1501814"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="287edf48-da72-359b-8f61-da5d4c45a270" resource="/proxy" action="W">
            <user identifier="c3f09c4d-0c92-3f45-b2e4-877def626d99"/>
            <user identifier="882592de-bfd2-35fa-b447-e6866f066684"/>
            <user identifier="bae641ef-8e45-3838-8dde-8e012ada53f5"/>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</authorizations>
```

oidc is working as expected and authentication is working via SSO. however, once authenticated I am getting below error on UI.
[image]

Those look like cert issued authority from toolkit. How to fix this? I tried several options and articles and none seem to work. The above `authorizers.xml` works because service is working. Otherwise, getting "unable to seed policy for" error.

Can anyone help?

Update: Checked nifi access log and found below:

```
2022-09-08 15:40:56,879 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.single.user.SingleUserAuthorizer Initializing Authorizer
2022-09-08 15:40:56,986 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileUserGroupProvider Users/Groups file loaded at Thu Sep 08 15:40:56 UTC 2022
2022-09-08 15:40:56,987 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileAccessPolicyProvider Added mapped node CN=nifi01, OU=NIFI (raw node identity CN=nifi01, OU=NIFI)
2022-09-08 15:40:56,987 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileAccessPolicyProvider Added mapped node CN=nifi03, OU=NIFI (raw node identity CN=nifi03, OU=NIFI)
2022-09-08 15:40:56,987 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileAccessPolicyProvider Added mapped node CN=nifi02, OU=NIFI (raw node identity CN=nifi02, OU=NIFI)
2022-09-08 15:40:57,000 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileAccessPolicyProvider Authorizations file loaded at Thu Sep 08 15:40:57 UTC 2022
2022-09-08 15:40:57,001 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.single.user.SingleUserAuthorizer Configuring Authorizer
2022-09-08 15:41:03,346 INFO [main] o.a.n.w.s.o.StandardOidcIdentityProvider OpenId Connect: Available clientAuthenticationMethods [client_secret_basic, client_secret_post, private_key_jwt, tls_client_auth]
2022-09-08 15:44:20,874 INFO [NiFi Web Server-19] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Started 172.20.0.1 [<anonymous>] GET https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user
2022-09-08 15:44:20,890 WARN [NiFi Web Server-19] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Failed 172.20.0.1 GET https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user [Anonymous authentication has not been configured.]
2022-09-08 15:44:34,264 INFO [NiFi Web Server-23] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Started 172.20.0.6 [<xyz@oidc.domain.com><CN=localhost, OU=NIFI>] GET https://nifi01:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user
2022-09-08 15:44:34,275 WARN [NiFi Web Server-23] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Failed 172.20.0.6 GET https://nifi01:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user [Untrusted proxy CN=localhost, OU=NIFI]
2022-09-08 15:46:26,568 INFO [NiFi Web Server-23] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Started 172.20.0.6 [<xyz@oidc.domain.com><CN=localhost, OU=NIFI>] GET https://nifi01:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user
2022-09-08 15:46:26,569 WARN [NiFi Web Server-23] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication Failed 172.20.0.6 GET https://nifi01:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user [Untrusted proxy CN=localhost, OU=NIFI]
```

Looks like `"CN=localhost, OU=NIFI"` is getting added by the ssl certificate? Maybe someone can explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Was able to fix the issue by adding Node Identity user to `accessPolicyProvider` and `userGroupProvide`r for the proxy on `authorizers.xml`.

`userGroupProvider`:

> ```
> <property name="Initial User Identity 5">CN=localhost, OU=NIFI</property>
> ```

accessPolicyProvider:

> ```
> <property name="Node Identity 4">CN=localhost, OU=NIFI</property>
> ```

Comment: How did you mount external authorizers.xml to the container? I receive "sed: cannot rename /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/sedaLv0Uo: Device or resource busy"

Comment: This looks like docker conflict with mounting the /opt drive. Please check if containers are mapped with correct volumes and write permission.